# How to apply label encoding to text data(list of list)

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am novice python data analyst trying to preprocess the text data (jsonl format) before it goes into Neural networks for topic modelling(VAE). I was able to clean the data and turn it into numpy array, further I wanted to apply label encoding to the cleaned text data but fail to do so. **How can one apply label encoding to list of list data format **?. The input data into label encoding is list of list and ouput has to be in same format.

```
numpy array format (type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)
[array([1131,  713,  857, 1130..........]) 
 array([ 142, 1346, 1918, 1893,   61,   62, 1922,967......]) ]) 
 array([135, 148,  14, 104, 154, 159, 136,  94, 149, 135, 117,  62, 130....]) 
 array([135, 148,  14, 104, 154, 159, 136......])...................................]
```

The code is this way(after cleaning):(list of list -strings)

```
    dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(process_texts) # creating a dictionary
    label_covid_data =[list(filter(lambda x: x != -1, dictionary.doc2idx(doc))) for doc in     process_texts] # converint it into numeric according to dictionary
    covid_train_data,covid_test_data = train_test_split(label_covid_data, test_size=0.2, random_state = 3456) # dividing into train and test data
    covid_train_narray = np.array([np.array(i) for i in covid_train_data]) # converting into numpy array format
    label = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() # applying label encoding 
    covid_data_labels = label.fit_transform([label.fit_transform(i) for i in covid_train_narray])
```

Error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    111         try:
--> 112             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    113         except TypeError:

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
     59     if uniques is None:
---> 60         uniques = sorted(set(values))
     61         uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-217-ebce4e37aad8> in <module>
  4 label = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  5 #movie_line_labels = label.fit_transform(covid_train_narray[0])
 ----> 6 covid_data_labels = label.fit_transform([label.fit_transform(i) for i in covid_train_narray])
  7 covid_data_labels
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
250         """
251         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
 --> 252         self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)
253         return y
254 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode, check_unknown)
    112             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    113         except TypeError:
-->     114             raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")
    115         return res
    116     else:

    TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data, so that we can easily reproduce your issue?

Comment: @cronoik, thank you so much, I have downloaded the data from (http://info.aylien.com/coronavirus-dataset?utm_campaign=Newsletters&utm_source=hs_email&utm_medium=email&utm_content=86862932&_hsenc=p2ANqtz--pbcVpWZJGfshCIO-uz5QQBI3BLPz94JM9dDeJlnmSb8N7Vi0mJPPGE8d-zEWpnuVQSz7x8l3NYxxwglv3x03v46XibQ&_hsmi=86862932) ,it is quite large 7Gb datasets (Coronavirus related news content).

Comment: We don't need the whole file. Just take 4 samples and convert it to an numpy array. Add the whole numpy arrays to your question. Make also sure that it is clear for us what are variables you have used in your code snippet.

Comment: @cronoik, please find data in this link(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVeQbqyjW_y7mNFOYLTvdCWTe9R1S8Iq/view?usp=sharing). The data.zip consists of text data(news articles about covid)- train,test and dictionary in np array format.